# How to Call Action in controller after jquery .each() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

We are developing web app using mvc and jquery mobile. I got stuck in one scenario. When user clicks a button I am changing the button colour and making a call to Action in controller using .each() function (based on the number of selected buttons) and  $.post also works well. Now after the end of .each() function I need to redirect user to a new controller. I tried the code below but its not working. Please guide me.

```
$(document).on('click', '#BtnReg', function (e) {

    var Deleted = 0;

    var DelectedAccount;


    $("#Container .red").each(function () {
        var ContainerIdforUser = $(this).parent().attr("id");

        DelectedAccount = $(this).attr("id");


        var detail = $('#' + ContainerIdforUser).find('.Detail').val();



        var url = "/Home/Index";


        $.post(url, {
            Info: detail
        },

        function (data) {

            if (data == "") {

                Deleted++;
            }

        });

    });


    if (Deleted > 0) {
        window.location.href = '/Personal/Account';

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please describe the error you are getting? You have spaces in your redirect URl not sure if that would be an issue but you could try "~/personal/account/" and see if that works

Comment: @KevDevMan : i tried. but when i debug the cursor is not comin to even window.location.href line. It keep on skiping the line

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
 window.location.href= '@Url.Action("Action_name", "Controller_name")'
```